# ET-tree in Henzinger and King (1995)

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following from the beginning of section 2.5 of Henzinger and King (FOCS 1995):

> We encode an arbitrary tree T with n vertices using a sequence of 2n - 1 symbols, which is generated as follows: Root the tree at an arbitrary vertex. 
>   Then traverse T in depth-first search order traversing each edge twice (once in each direction) and visiting every degree-d vertex d times, except for the root which is visited d + 1 times. Each time any vertex u is encountered, we call this an occurrence of the vertex. Let ET(T) be the sequence of node occurrences representing an arbitrary tree T.
>
> For each spanning tree T(B) of a block B of H_i each occurrence of ET(T(B)) is stored in a node of a balanced binary search tree, called the ET(T(B))-tree. For each vertex u in T(B), we arbitrarily choose one occurrence to be the active occurrence of u.
>   With the active occurrence of each vertex v, we keep the (unordered) list of nontree edges in B which are incident to u, stored as a balanced binary tree.  Each node in the ET-tree contains the number of nontree edges stored in its subtree.
>
> Using this data structure for each level we can sample an edge of T_1 in time O(logn).

My questions follow some explanation of some terms.

From section 2.2,

> A *block* is a maximal set of nodes that are biconnected.

H_i is a subgraph of G, whose dynamic biconnectivity (which is much of the topic of the paper) we wish to maintain. (More specifically, the edge set of G has been partitioned into *l* = log(|E(G)|) sets and each set induces a graph H_i for 1 <= *i* <= *l*.)

Here's my understanding. Pick some T(B) of H_i. The key of each active node in the corresponding ET tree is the number of "nontree edges in B [that] are incident to u". The value of each node is the appropriate list of edges.

Questions:

- To finalise the ET tree, we have each node store the sum of the keys of all nodes in its subtree (including the node itself)?
- The list for each node is not a balanced tree, right?
- If only the active nodes matter, why create an ET-tree in the first place?
- To sample an edge, we generate a number between 1 and |E(B))|. If the number is between 1 and |V(B)| - 1 then we're choosing some tree edge. Otherwise, we traverse the balanced tree and then select the appropriate edge from a list?